# AWK - Max Variables?

Tags: awk

Why does the first statement work but not the second?  I'm trying to add an additional two (one shown) variables to do another comparison, but the second instance errors out.

**1st Instance**

```
awk 'f1=substr($1,0,9), f2=substr($3,0,9){if(f1==f2)print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

**2nd Instance**

```
awk 'f1=substr($1,0,9), f2=substr($3,0,9), f3=substr($1,5,3){if(f1==f2)print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file

awk: cmd. line:1: f1=substr($1,0,9), f2=substr($3,0,9), f3=substr($1,5,3){if(f1==f2)print $1,$2,$3,$4,16}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                     ^ syntax error
```

**File**

```
TULSHDRJ02 ae0.0 KSCYBBRJ01 ae1.0
MTC3BBRJ02 ae4.0 KSCYBBRJ01 ae6.0
KSCYBBRJ01 ae2.0 KSCYBBRJ02 ae2.0
MTC1BBRJ02 ae4.0 KSCYBBRJ02 ae6.0
```

**Output**

```
KSCYBBRJ01 ae2.0 KSCYBBRJ02 ae2.0
```

Comment: First one acts as address range, second is multiple commands in a row, Why comma?

Comment: What were you hoping those commands would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'substr($1,1,9)==substr($3,1,9){print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

since you're printing everything you can drop the action part

```
$ awk 'substr($1,1,9)==substr($3,1,9)' file
```

or, for **DRY**

```
$ awk 'function s(v) {return substr(v,1,9)} 
       s($1)==s($3)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

The general program structure of an awk program is as follows:

```
condition { action [; action [ ; ... ]] }
```

Multiple actions are separated by ; or newline.

Both the condition and the block of actions are optional. When you omit the condition

```
{ action [; action [ ; ... ]] }
```

... actions will be always executed. If you omit the actions:

```
condition
```

... the default action is `print`.

Multiple of those blocks can be put in a row:

```
cond1 { action1 } cond2 {action2} ...
```

Note: newline can be always used as a delimiter (for multiline programs)

---

I guess you wanted:

```
awk '{f1=substr($1,0,9);f2=substr($3,0,9)} f1==f2{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

... or in multiline form:

```
awk '# Runs on every line
     {
         f1=substr($1,0,9)
         f2=substr($3,0,9)
      }

      # Runs only if condition is met
      f1==f2 {
          print $1,$2,$3,$4
      }'
```

**But not quite!**

It should be

```
awk '{f1=substr($1,1,9);f2=substr($3,1,9)} f1==f2{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

instead of

```
awk '{f1=substr($1,0,9);f2=substr($3,0,9)} f1==f2{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

Note that string, field and array indices in awk start at 1, not 0.

---

Please check also [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa), which shows how the command can be simplified.

Comment: Yes, almost every thing except `ARGV`.

Comment: ARGV starts as 1 too for the script arguments. ARGV[0] is used as a convenience to store the name of the script. There are other edge cases though like the seps array thats the 4th arg to split() in GNU awk but I was going for the common stuff.